# How to use dataframe from a function and return response to download csv file - Flask

Tags: python, function, flask, python-requests, jinja2

I'm trying to create a download/export csv file button, but I'm having issues with it.
I get this errror "TypeError: csv_download() missing 1 required positional argument: 'CSV'" when I try to return response. I have test it without calling the function and it work so I guess I missed something...I have also added a print ("print('this is CSV file:', test)") and it work but when I click on the Download button I get the error mentionned above..

```
@app.route("/result", methods=['POST','GET'])
def result():

mapping_query = """select * from test"""

from datetime import datetime
start_time = datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)

Query = pd.read_sql_query(mapping_query, conn)

dataset = pd.DataFrame(Query)
dataset.set_index('itemID', inplace=True)
print(dataset)

csv_data = dataset.to_csv(index=False, encoding='utf-8')
# print(csv_data)
csv_download(csv_data)

Size_mapped = len(dataset)
print('Size Mapped with YP :', Size_mapped)
flash(Size_mapped)

results = list(dataset.values.tolist())

fieldnames = dataset.columns.values

end_time = datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)

elapsed_time_known = end_time - start_time
print("\n")
print('>>>>> Time elapsed from beginning: <<<<<', elapsed_time_known)

return render_template('result.html', times=[elapsed_time_known], results=results, fieldnames=fieldnames, zip=zip)


@app.route("/csv_download", methods=['GET'])
def csv_download(CSV):
test = (CSV)

print("\n")
print('this is CSV file:', test)
response = Response(test,mimetype='text/csv')

response.headers.set("Content-Disposition", "attachment", filename="Export_Merchant_Validator_Tool.csv")

return response
```

Here is the button in result.html

```
<form style="margin-left: 38%" method="GET" action="/csv_download" enctype="multipart/form-data">

 <button style="height: 50%; width: 38%; color: white; background-color: #696969; border-color: #696969; "  type="submit" value="Submit"  class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" > Download dataset as csv </button>   

</form>
```

Thanks in advance for your time and help !

Comment: According to the error message, a non-existent argument was criticized. If you expect an argument at the endpoint, this should also be defined in your rule for the route. Please also correct your indentation out of consideration for those who should answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following example should meet your needs.
The data is queried again in the route and transmitted as a download using a [stream](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#binary-i-o) and the [send_file](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.send_file) function.

```
import io 
from flask import send_file

@app.route('/csv_download')
def csv_download():
    sql = """select * from test"""
    df = pd.read_sql_query(sql, conn, index_col='itemID')
    return send_file(
        io.BytesIO(df.to_csv(index=False, encoding='utf-8').encode()),
        as_attachment=True,
        attachment_filename='Export_Merchant_Validator_Tool.csv',
        mimetype='text/csv')
```

You do not necessarily need a form if you do not want to pass any further parameters in a GET request.

```
<a href="{{ url_for('csv_download') }}" download>Download</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help !! I have tried that and indeed it worked. But it will run another sql query (that take at least one minute to run). That's why I have the result function who is going to run the query display the dataframe from it as table in result.html and then I'll have a download button to export this as csv. Do you see my point ?

Comment: @iamgda I understand the problem, but unfortunately I have no solution at the moment. It would of course be possible to cache the request somehow, but that could also cause unwanted side effects. Sorry, I guess my knowledge is insufficient for this.

Comment: @Deltef thank you so much for your help, appreciate it !